# How to handle 000 padding in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I expected result is sometimes getting padded with 000 or 0000 or 0

Expected : 2
Actual : 0002 or 02

The comparison is failing where it should pass.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with numbers, use `Should Be Equal As X`, where X is either `Numbers` if they are floats, or `Integers` - if whole numbers. The keyword will cast the compared values, and do comparison where the padding doesn't matter:

```
Should Be Equal As Numbers    002.9080    000002.908   # will pass
```

If any of the arguments cannot be casted - they have a letter inside them, for example, the keyword will fail.